# GWT with clients: Web, IOS, Android. Starting new project

Tags: android, ios, gwt, code-reuse, google-inbox

When I read that Google Inbox application reuse 70% of code for all three main clients (web,ios,android) I have been encouraged to learn GWT, as inbox was written mainly using gwt. Additionaly incoming Gwt Singularity framework convince me to this platform.

For now I will focus on web client, but in future I would like to expand the app to Android and IOS.

So I've started new project, have wrote some basic ui, entities and dao.

Now I need Your help.

Please give me some information about what transport mechanizm choose to support all of these three platforms.

I consider to user RequestFactory (less code, more job done- for me).
I now that RequestFactory supports Android, but couldn't found information about supporting IOS.

Second choose is JSON marchaling and gwtResty library. I supose that will work.

Another think is how to connect Android and IOS client to GWT backend?

Please give me some help, links, or Your experience on that subject.

Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/futureplatforms/kirin